# jQuery UI (un)resizable with Redactor editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, redactor

I have a **resizable DIV** on my page, as soon as I init the Redactor editor on that element, I lose the resize feature. (even if I try to attach it back later, after Redactor is destroyed!)

http://jsfiddle.net/imehesz/BjM3g/

```
$(function(){
var $res = $("#resizethis");
var $save = $("#save");
var $edit = $("#edit");

$res.resizable();

$edit.on("click", function(){
    $res.redactor({
        toolbar: false,
        focus: true
    });
    $save.prop("disabled", false);
});

$save.on("click",function(){
    $res.redactor("destroy");
    $save.prop("disabled", true);
});
```

});

thanks

Answer (score 1):

well, this is one solution, let me know if you know a better one ...

I had to manually destroy/re-create the resizable() call like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/imehesz/BjM3g/4/

```
$(function(){
var $res = $("#resizethis");
var $save = $("#save");
var $edit = $("#edit");

$res.resizable();

$edit.on("click", function(){
    $res.resizable("destroy");
    $res.redactor({
        toolbar: false,
        focus: true
    });
    $save.prop("disabled", false);
});

$save.on("click",function(){
    $res.redactor("destroy");
    $save.prop("disabled", true);
    $res.resizable();
});
```

});

I hope it will help somebody (else) too...

--iM